# iPhoneX: Extend tableview all the way to the bottom of the display (not safe area)

Tags: ios, iphone-x

Is it possible to extend the tableView all the way to the bottom of the display?  If so, how does one do it?  I currently have it set to safe areas.  I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

In my current app, the bottom home button is just white, blocking the tableView:

[image]

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the right link.  closing this.

Comment: you need only to change the bottom constraint's constant if this what you meant